# Do loop while input isn't a or b?

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I'm doing the finishing touches for a class project and I'm adding in a safety net for one of my user inputs. I have it set so that if the user puts in "1" or "2", the data they enter will be displayed in different ways. I want to add a method that prevents the user from entering anything other than "1" or "2". Here is the code for it.

```
do
{
System.out.println("Please type either '1' or '2'.");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
a = scan.nextInt();
}
while (a != (1||2));
//after user enters 1 or 2, return the choice
return a;
```

I've been reading about the operands and logic, but I'm kind of stuck. I've been badgering my teacher the whole way through so I figured I'd give him a break since I'm not his only student. My error is saying "bad operand types for binary operator '||'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common misconception when learning programming.

You, as a human, can easily read the statement which reads like this: "while a is not 1 or 2", but the computer has to follow certain rules, and one of the rules is that "or" takes precedence.

What this means is that it first triest to figure out what "1 or 2" means, since basically, your statement is similar to this:

```
while (a != SOMETHING);
```

`||` in the Java language is "logical or", which translates to this: Take the two values (called operands) on each side of the `||` (called the operator), and combine them according to the rules of "logical or".

"logical or" uses two boolean values, which can only be True or False, and since you asked it to use the operator with numbers, that's why you get that particular error message.

If you had tried using the single pipe, `|`, the compiler might have stopped complaining, but it would still not do what you want it to do.

`1 or 2` when dealing with numbers, using the `|` operator, which is the "bitwise or" operators, you would get the two numbers combined to form the number 3. You can read more about "bitwise operators" if you want to know why.

In short, you cannot write your comparison like this.

In programming languages, comparisons are done two values at a time, ie. one against another, so your only choice is to expand the expression to compare twice.

Here is some equivalent expressions which will give you what you want:

```
while (a != 1 && a != 2);
```

or this:

```
while (!(a == 1 || a == 2));
```

To be hones, I like the first better.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem and I learned something as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is `(a != 1 && a!=2)` - You actually want to exit the loop when a is either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do separate conditional statements for `a!= 1` and `a!= 2`.

Your conditional statement should look something like this:

```
(a!=1) && (a!=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are trying to write code that makes sense read as English, but it doesn't work like that. The `||` operator takes two expressions and returns if one or the other is `true`. That means what you have written doesn't make sense.

The simplest way to replace this is to expand it out:

```
a != 1 && a != 2
```

(We need to use `&&` as we are checking that neither of them is true).

Note that this can become verbose and awkward. Alternatively, a good replacement (given you have a lot of values to check) is a membership check in a collection (a `Set` is a good choice as you are guaranteed a O(1) membership test). E.g:

```
Set<Integer> possibles = new HashSet<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(possibles, new Integer[] {1, 2, ...});
while (!possibles.contains(a)) {
    ...
```

Comment: `Arrays.asSet()` ?? Where does that come from?

Comment: @jlordo Ugh, I went ahead and assumed that it existed, apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat an `int` like pseudo-`regex`. Replace

```
while (a != (1||2));
```

with

```
while (a != 1 && a!= 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your while loop condition

```
((a!=1) && (a!=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
while (a != 1 && a != 2)
```

because it's the equivalent of **not** `(a == 1 || a == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

The binary operator '||' needs two boolean operand on both side. Since, your operands are integers, this is a syntax error.

You should do it in this way:

```
do{
// core of the loop...
}while(a!=1 && a!=2);
```